# Main method not found in class First, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: selenium

```
import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


 public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("www.facebook.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}

I am getting this error when I am trying to run it in Eclipse Kepler:
```

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'Jyoti-PC', ip: '192.168.112.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=37.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: a35eb217-b3b2-4de8-abc2-4e72ceb06916
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:306)
    at first.main(first.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'Jyoti-PC', ip: '192.168.112.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.get(file:///C:/Users/Jyoti/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous573077067589922398webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10160)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Jyoti/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous573077067589922398webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12282)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Jyoti/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous573077067589922398webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12287)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Jyoti/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous573077067589922398webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12229)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Main method not found in class Calculate, please define the main method as: public static void main(String\[\] args)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268262/error-main-method-not-found-in-class-calculate-please-define-the-main-method-a)

Comment: that one i resolved but i m still getting problm @saifur

Comment: hey.. did you tried like driver.get("http://www.facebook.com"); means starting the url with http://  ?  but not sure why import org.apache.xpath.operations.String; is imported as those two line required it?

Comment: sorry in above comment http:// is not displaying in get method..

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.**WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function**

This exception happens because you are trying to get() a URL that's not prefixed with http:// or https://

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```