# Why can not pass "int" as argument in main method

Tags: java

In java when i pass `int` as argument in main method i got error

> "Error: Main method not found in class dynamicInput, please define the main method as:
> public static void main(String[] args)
> or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application"

Here down is my code:

```
public class dynamicInput {
    public static void main(int a, int b) {
       System.out.printf("%d %d", a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error clearly says what you should do. Did you try doing it?

Comment: The error message seems clear: you have two `int` arguments, but one `String[]` one is expected. (Also, the Java convention is that class names are in TitleCase, not camelCase — ideally, your class should be named `DynamicInput`, and live in `DynamicInput.java`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Main method not found in class Calculate, please define the main method as: public static void main(String\[\] args)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268262/error-main-method-not-found-in-class-calculate-please-define-the-main-method-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tell evething. either you `forget to declare main method` or `somthing missing in main method declaration`. In Java Programming The **`main()`** method is a special method that serves as the externally exposed entrance point by which a Java program can be run. To compile a Java program, you doesn't really need a **`main()`** method in your program. But, while execution JVM searches for the **`main()`** method and starts executing from it.

You declare int argument in main method but it shoud be `String[] args`. now one question arise in your mind **`Why String args[]?`** because When you run a Java program from a command line, you are allowed to pass data into that program as `comnand line arguments`.Your Java program will run from a `main()` method, and the arguments you typed on the command line will appear to the Java program as Strings in that array.

Here down is right syntex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Some code inside main function....
}
```

And your code should be:

```
public class Main {
    static void printSomeNumber()
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        System.out.printf("%d %d", a, b);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        printSomeNumber();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to you can't use different type of variable in main method as java compiler will search for main method with String[] as parameter. you should only use following method as it's an entry point for your console application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....
    ....
}
```

you can get your value provided into console from array of args

so you can do like following

```
public class DynamicInput {

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.printf("%d %d", a, b);    
    }
}
```

you can read about main method here [Java main method](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-main-method)